# Webscraping w/ BeautifulSoup: Assign H4 Header ID to Elements in a List

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm doing webscraping and there are several h4 tags with lists underneath each tag. I'd like to **scrape** the elements of each list and assign it to the id of each h4 tag. Here's the HTML:

```
<h4 class="dataHeaderWithBorder" id="Production" name="production">Production</h4>
<ul class="simpleList">
<li><a href="/company/co0308?ref_=xtco_co_1">Red Claw </a></li>
<li><a href="/company/co0386?ref_=xtco_co_2">Haven </a></li>
<li><a href="/company/co0487?ref_=xtco_co_3">Frame</a></li>
</ul>
<h4 class="dataHeaderWithBorder" id="Distribution" name="Distribution">Distribution</h4>
<ul class="simpleList">
<li><a href="/company/co0017?ref_=xtco_co_1">Broadside Attractions</a>    </li>
<li><a href="/company/co0208?ref_=xtco_co_2"> Global Acquisitions</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I'd like the data to look like:

```
Production, Red Claw
Production, Haven
Production, Frame
Distribution, Broadside Attractions
Distribution, Global Acquisitions
```

I can get all of the elements of both lists, but I can't get the id. My code looks as follows:

```
    for h4 in soup.find_all('h4', attrs={'class':'dataHeaderWithBorder'}):
        id = h4.get_text()
        #print(id)
        for ul in h4.find_all('ul', attrs={'class':'simpleList'}):
            #print(ul)                
            # Find the items that mention a budget
            productionCompany = ul.find_all('a')
            for company in productionCompany:
                text = company.get_text()
                print(id, text)
                productionComps.append(id, text)
```

I can't figure out how to grab the id from each h4 tag. If I drop the first two lines and replace h4.find_all with soup.find_all, my output ends up looking like this.

```
Red Claw
Haven
Frame
Broadside Attractions
Global Acquisition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using zip

```
h4_list=soup.find_all('h4', attrs={'class':'dataHeaderWithBorder'})
ul_list=soup.find_all('ul', attrs={'class':'simpleList'})
productionComps=[]
for h4,ul in zip(h4_list,ul_list):
    id_ = h4.get_text()
    productionCompany = ul.find_all('a')
    for company in productionCompany:
        text = company.get_text()
        print(id_, text)
        productionComps.append((id_, text))
```

Comment: Wow--super simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
id = h4.get_text()
```

`id` isn't the item text; it's an *attribute*.  Element attributes in beautifulsoup are accessed like a dictionary.  Try this:

```
item_id = h4['id']
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
d = [[i.name, i.text] for i in soup(data, 'html.parser').find_all(re.compile('h4|a'))]
new_d = [list(b) for _, b in groupby(d, key=lambda x:x[0] == 'h4')]
grouped = [[new_d[i][0][-1], [a for _, a in new_d[i+1]]] for i in range(0, len(new_d), 2)]
result = '\n'.join('\n'.join(f'{a}, {i}' for i in b) for a, b in grouped)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Production, Red Claw 
Production, Haven 
Production, Frame
Distribution, Broadside Attractions
Distribution,  Global Acquisitions
```

Comment: This works, but it's really complicated and I can't explain why it works. Thanks for the help.